# URL safety in Django E-commerce

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

I'm working with my own e-commerce in Django and the payments are handled like this:

1. I have a checkout view with a slug (since I'm working with only two products) where the user sumbits their shipping data.
2. Then they are redirected to the payment URL, that is guided by a Primary Key. It looks like this:

   http://....../payment/24

The problem that worries me is the simplicity of the id, it's just a number that anyone can access with the URL. Is there any way to make this safer? I was thinking about hashing the URL, but didn't find any tool for that.

note: It's a guest checkout, so I'm not dealing with registered users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your concern and there is a super easy way to make it more secure. There is a field named `UUIDField`.

Let me simply write here how to use.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class YourModelName(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks! let me try that out in a moment and i'll get you back

Comment: Okay, once you had it ready in your model, `pk` will be made longer with UUID format.

Comment: There you go. Thank you!